# Google Sheets Ignore Certain Cell Changes/Updates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a script, in Google Sheets, that sends an email when any cell in a column changes. (this works)  However, I want to ignore if the cell changed from "blank" to "value".  I.e. Only send emails if the value changed from a previously entered value.  --Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I worked on this some more and here is the solution I came up with.  It seems to work.  Hopefully this will benefit others.  Posted below.

Comment: Include in your question what your research into this topic (adding code guards to an edit-triggered function, a *very common* topic here on SO) revealed, what you tried, and the results of those attempts to resolve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @tehhowch - Updated my original question to hopefully benefit others.  Appreciate change to up vote. --thanks

Comment: You should post solutions as answers, not as edits to your question. This way, they can be upvoted / set as the answer, and clearly identify to all parties that the question has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposed answer.  It has been tested in production.

- Triggers on "edit"
- If change is to an already populated cell, email is sent
- If change is to an empty cell, no email is sent
- Email sender is a "noreply" default email (FYI: "noreply" option
  seems to override "name" attribute)
- Email includes values from other cells in same row as change

Here is the code:

```
function sendNotificationCellChange(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var oldvalue = e.oldValue;
  var newvalue = e.value;

  var recipients = "you@gmail.com" + "," + "me@gmail.com";
  var cust_name = '';
  var proj_num = '';
  var subject = '';
  var body = '';

  if (range.getA1Notation().indexOf('K') != -1 && oldvalue !== undefined && newvalue !== undefined) {
    cust_name = sheet.getRange('B'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue();
    proj_num = sheet.getRange('C'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue();

    var subject = 'Ship Date Has Changed: \"'+newvalue+'\" Customer: \"'+cust_name+'\" Project Number: "'+proj_num+'"';
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body, {
      name: 'Schedule',
      noReply: 'true'
    });
  }
};
```